# Icon tag in xml file

Tags: xml, google-maps, icons, kml

I am working on an app where I want to display a kml file overlayed on google maps. This kml file consists of markers of which I would like to set a custom icon for them. The icons are stored on my pc.

My question is how am I able to access these icons from my kml file in order to display them on the map.

The following is what I attempted to do, by storing the icon in the same file of the kkml file, BUT it does not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>route</name>
    <Placemark>
      <name>445</name>
      <description>Market</description>
      <Style>
            <IconStyle>
              <Icon>
                <href>0.png</href>
              </Icon>
            </IconStyle>
      </Style>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>14.5139685555926,35.898079278121</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have just solved it was a problem from javascript where I have set the marker options rather than from the kml file. Thanks again :)

Comment: A quick question? can I display a local icon image as a marker? since i have tested only taken an image from web but image stored locally it is not working. @geocodezip

Comment: You still haven't said where and how you are trying to display the marker.

Comment: By storing the icon in the same file as KML file do you mean you're created a KMZ file that includes both the KML file (e.g. doc.kml) and a set of icons?

Comment: No. I have used a normal file. What does it really mean to create a kmz file and store both kml and icons in it? @JasonM1

Answer (score 2):

You have a choice of storing the icons at the same level as the KML (for example on the same web server in the same folder) or sub-folder such that the relative URLs resolve correctly or embedded within a [KMZ](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives) file, which is basically a "ZIP" file with a root KML file along with any number of other KML files and inline icons or overlays referenced in the KML.

Example-1:
http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/kmz/balloon/balloon-image-rel.kml

Here the KML references an image relative to the KML file:

```
 <description>
        <![CDATA[
        Here is an image:
        <img src="images/googleearth.gif"/>
        ]]>
      </description>
```

On some platforms the image does not work but if you download both the KML and image locally then it will display as you would expect with an inline image.

Example-2:

http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/kmz/balloon/balloon-image-rel.kmz

In this example the image *googleearth.gif* is stored inside the KMZ file in a sub-folder images so downloading the KMZ file includes both the KML and the image.

You layout the KMZ file as you would content on a web server.

[Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport) says it supports KMZ (compressed KML, including attached images).

Comment: So there is no way to refer to an image from local side.? Since i am working on localhost for the moment.@JasonM1

Comment: If the icon exists at same folder as KML file then it may resolve correctly. Depends on how Maps API resolves local links. If package as KMZ then icon is always co-located with KML file. You can use absolute URLs to images in development to get things working in your app.